# flash overlay snagging on underlying divs

Tags: flash, shadowbox

Has anyone come across this before and know a solution?

I'm using Shadowbox to overlay a flash file on my page, but the movement within the flash file causes it to break or "shear" where the movie comes across the divs in the HTML hidden below.

The screenshot shows it far better than I could explain ;)

If you move the mouse, or tap the keyboard to "focus" the screen back on the flash it all works seamlessly. Interestingly this seems worse in Firefox than the other browsers.

All help much appreciated :D

[Flash error image](http://www.contentformula.com/images/flash_error.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the Z-Index of your flash object is set to be higher than that of the divs below. Am I correct?

Also, what value are you using for the wmode parameter you're passing to the flash object tag (or embed)?

You should take a look at:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html

Comment: Hiya, yeah the settings are as follows. Basically - transparent and slightly seethrough onto the content below.

Flash
wmode=transparent

Shadowbox
bgcolor:#FFFFFF at 60% opacity

Comment: Hiya, 

I've worked it out I think, although I don't have an easy answer. In Firefox, which was always the main culprit, if the underlaying divs have "overflow:hidden" or "overflow:auto" then that causes the bug. If you remove these CSS properties, the problem is resolved.

All other browsers work ok, no matter what.

Now I need to work out how I can get rid of my overflows without breaking my div layout :P

Comment: Appears to be related to this bug - either need to abandon wmode:transparent, remove all "overflow" css statements or do dodgy stuff with javascript.